# Proper npm install --save behavior?

Tags: npm

All documentation I have seen indicates that using `--save` argument with `npm install` should update the dependencies in `package.json`.

This does not work for me. Packages install successfully without any error in the npm console output, but `package.json' remains unchanged.

What am I missing? I have seen nothing in my research that indicates corner cases where the `package.json` would not update.

EDIT

I have a simple Visual Studio project. The package.json is empty as it will not be published.

```
{ }
```

`npm i karma --save`

Executed in npm console located in root of project where `package.json` exists.

A lot of output. No errors. Successful install. Five warnings.

```
npm WARN package.json @ No description
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @ No README data
npm WARN package.json @ No license field.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
```

Comment: Show us your `package.json`, your command, and your output.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of node (`node --version`) and npm (`npm --version`) are you using? What is the exit code of the npm command you ran?

Comment: node v0.12.4 and npm v2.10.1. I don't see an exit code. There a 5 warnings, a couple of commands related to node-gyp and then it lists the tree structure of karma and its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be an issue with the file encoding.

By default Visual Studio encodes JSON files using UTF8+BOM.

For some reason, npm does not like this. Installation completes successfully without error, but it fails to write to `package.json`.

I re-encoded to UTF8 using Sublime, and everything started working.